# MySQL Not loading Database File from /usr/local/mysql/data

Tags: mysql, database, macos, schema

Hey Guys so the other day I was running a database schema in the mysql workbench on my mac. I had added tables populated the data and tried to run some big queries. The server died and now when I connect to my local host instance I cannot find my database. However I can still see my database file in /usr/local/mysql/data/

Can any one help me work out how to start mysql server again and get it to load in the file?

I just dont' understand why it can no longer see the schema..

Connecting as localhost, using root, both workbench and terminal can't see the file. However the file is here:

[image]
The file I want is AM_DUMPS

When I try and load it from SQL Workbench I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the data directory is owned by MySQL or mysqld is not launched as the mysql user. It looks like something along those lines. You may have to adjust the permissions to make sure that mysql is the owner.

Comment: This seems like a really good suggestion. Could you give some guidance as to how to check this? @hatem-jaber ? Is this like a terminal Chmod thing?

Comment: Either a chmod or chown, not sure exactly without looking at your system. You need to be careful, check before you make any changes who the owner is and permissions, etc...

Comment: someone provided an example for you, I'm not sure if "Chown" is right, I believe it should be "chown", not sure on a Mac though. I guess he removed it.